# как автоматический обновлять данные Datagridivew при изменение в базе данных

Tags: c#, mysql

пытаюсь обновить данные в Datagridview, кроме установки таймера можно ли автоматический обновлять содержимое Datagridview когда в базе данных происходит изменения? благодарю!

```
public void view() 
    {
        var Connect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MysqlConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(Connect))
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            conn.Open();
            command.Connection = conn;
            command.CommandText = @"select line.id, line.line_number, line.datetime from line";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
            dataGridView1.Columns["id"].Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: В MySQL нет средств уведомления клиента об изменениях в данных. Так что только поллинг.

Comment: @jun66, посмотрите сюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717824/notification-system-using-php-and-mysql может вас осенит?

Comment: Десктопное приложение не должно быть клиентом БД напрямую. Был бы сервер и работали бы с ним через API, проблем бы с уведомлениями не было, потому что сервер всегда бы знал, когда в базе происходят изменения.

Comment: @aepot,  прощу прошения, есть сервер, локальный wamp.  задача такая , с одного компьютера локальной сети изменились данные в другом компьютере отображались эти изменения

Comment: Ну установите подключение через какой-нибудь веб-сокет с клиентом или как угодно ещё и шлите ему уведомление.